# Programmatically invoke Html File plus Css and Javascript With ShowCase

Tags: webview, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I am unpacking a Zip File and load the index.html like that

```
MyWebViewControl.NavigateToLocalStreamUri(MyUrl, new MyStreamUriResolver());
```

But it only shows Plain Html. The

```
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

for example doesn't get invoked. I don't have any idea why it doesn't work.
I don't get it. Why can i load a WebPage like stackoverflow with css and javascript, but when i try to load my own Html File it doesn't work.
**Any suggestions how i can fix the problem?**

EDIT:
[ShowCase for my Problem](https://github.com/bastiankemmer/ShowCaseApp)
Read.me First!
JQuery link is not necessary. You can try it with only a css link too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you get the whole content:

```
private async Task<IInputStream> GetContent(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            var arr = path.Split('/');
            var localFolder = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;
            var folder = await localFolder.GetFolderAsync("myhtmlunzip");
            var file = await folder.GetFileAsync(arr[arr.Length-1]);

            IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read).AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (true)
            {
                Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader reader = new DataReader(stream);
                await reader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);
                var fileContent = reader.ReadString((uint)stream.Size);
                stream.Seek(0);
            }
            return stream;

        }
        catch
        {
            throw new Exception("Path is invalid");
        }
    }
```

[Informations (MSDN LINK)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigatetolocalstreamuri.aspx)